# Leaflet pop up fade out animation

Tags: leaflet, popup, animation

When a popup is opened with Leaflet a nice fade in animation is played. When you close the popup however it abruptly disappears. Does anyone know how to play a fade out animation when closing the popup?

I am using Leaflet 0.7.3.

Comment: It is included for the coming Leaflet release, 0.8: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#misc-usability-improvements However I haven't been able to locate the commit where its added...

Comment: Great, thank you for the link. I think I'll just wait for the official release then. Apart from potential API breaking changes do you know if the current 0.8 is stable enough to use in a production environment?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know whether 0.8 is already stable enough to use in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup fade out animation is [included for the coming 0.8 release](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#misc-usability-improvements).